# What precisely about Zoom is not secure?

Tags: web-application, account-security, threat-mitigation

My agency (which isn't a high security-risk, top-secret place) has an almost zero tolerance rule for Zoom and I am curious why.  We are told to use WebEx instead but I fail to see why WebEx is more secure than Zoom.  I don't think it's merely an E2E encryption issue because we are allowed to use the web-based version of Zoom but not the app.  This is a rather annoying policy largely because all of our collaborators use/rely on Zoom and the web-based version is at best kludgy.

Other agencies and labs that *are* high security-risk (e.g., military contracts and security clearance requirements) have .gov Zoom accounts and seem fine with it.  So my inclination is to think this is just our OCIO over reacting or somehow that we don't have a contract with Zoom prevents its use.  However, they repeatedly send out alerts about how big of a threat Zoom is to IT security yet they never explain why.

So why is the Zoom app viewed as a security threat?

Comment: There are many results when you search for "zoom security issues" or similar. July 2019 had a particularly bad vulnerability which opened up remote webcam access even after uninstalling the software (web app not affected, obviously).

Comment: The fact that your company has established WebEx use for many years before Zoom got in to play makes me ask another question as a sysadmin: What's wrong with WebEx that users still swear by Zoom? Why go for another enterprise Zoom licensing system when you already have WebEx? 

Your admins KNOW WebEX and it's management platforms. New software, especially the end-user-installed kind is always an extra attack vector...

Comment: Have you asked your IT team?

Comment: Note that Zoom has a separate government version of the service that meets FEDRAMP standards. You cannot compare the FEDRAMP version to the commercial version.

Comment: @Nomad - It's more that we are part of telecons with places that solely use Zoom so we are forced to use Zoom to participate.  However, the web-based version has issues and greatly limits our ability to participate/contribute.  Those same institutions, for whatever reason, do not like WebEx.  This isn't my choice/preference so much as a necessity due to external institutional choices.

Comment: @schroeder - Yes, we ask the IT team questions like this and are given completely uninteresting or uninformative answers like "It's a security risk" without further clarification.  Yes I am aware of the government version but we are not allowed to use it according to our OCIO (even though adjacent labs/agencies are, as I mentioned).  Like I said in my comment to Nomad, this isn't really something we want so much as need to interact with our colleagues at universities (all of whom prefer Zoom).

Comment: So then your answer is simply found with the google search query "zoom app vulnerabilities". Why your IT team sees it as a threat is not something we could possibly answer.

Comment: @schroeder - Believe it or not, I have googled that and other phrases looking for differences between WebEx and Zoom.  The problem is that most of the articles I find are effectively opinion pieces, not rigorous point-by-point analysis.  I'm a physicist not a computer scientist so my knowledge of appropriate journal articles on this topic is greatly limited.  What I did find in recent articles is that the security differences were minor (early-to-mid 2020 they were indeed greater), thus my confusion.

Comment: Your problem statement was not to compare the 2 apps, but to know the vulnerabilities in the Zoom app. That's not a matter of opinion, and there are very detailed breakdowns. The Toms Hardware Guide's rolling article (updated as of the end of Feb) being the famous one. You don't need a journal article. The blog posts are written for the layperson.

Comment: @schroeder - Yes, perhaps I should have been more specific in my question.  I will check out that hardware guide blog.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is asking for the current state of vulnerabilities in a paricular product. Any answer will age poorly and there are active lists online that keep track of this particular app. We cannot do a security comparison between apps (Zoom and Webex) and we can't tell you why your IT dep lets you use the web client but not the app.

Comment: I think this is a a good question and resulted in helpful responses, even if some of them were passive-aggressive or aggressive-aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

Early Zoom use did not properly limit access with passwords and was subject to *Zoom Bombing*, uninvited people joining the meetings. Zoom also mislead with statements about E2E encryption when in fact it was no such thing, as a result it got a lot of negative press.

Conversely the open source product Jitsi emphasized security.

In both cases, it's all in the details.

Recently Zoom has enabled E2E encryption capabilities, comparable to Jitsi.

*True E2E encryption **was** limited to direct one-to-one person connections  for Zoom, and all the others as well, because trying to manage dozens or hundreds of individual encryption keys and cross connects is a nightmare.*

**[Correction]**
Apparently Zoom does now offer multiuser E2E encryption. According to their [support page](https://support.zoom.us/hc/en-us/articles/360048660871-End-to-end-E2EE-encryption-for-meetings):

> **How does Zoom provide end-to-end encryption?** Zoom’s E2EE offering uses
> public key cryptography. In short, the keys for each Zoom meeting are
> generated by participants’ machines, not by Zoom’s servers. Encrypted
> data relayed through Zoom’s servers is indecipherable by Zoom, since
> Zoom’s servers do not have the necessary decryption key. This key
> management strategy is similar to that used by most end-to-end
> encrypted messaging platforms today.

Non-E2E Multiperson meetings for Zoom and everyone else is performed by connecting to a central management server that handles all the cross connects. Encryption is User-to-Server, but everything on the server is decrypted.

**The security issue is, who controls the server and where is it?**

Plain old default just use Zoom runs on servers controlled by Zoom throughout the world. I've seen Zoom servers in Australia handling meetings in the U.S.. Zoom, like all the others, offers the capability to run your own servers for greater control and security, **but user and meeting metadata are still managed in the Zoom public cloud**.

Other products, like Jitsi, allow complete secure isolation if set up that way. I believe WebEx supports an isolated setup as well, but I'm not positive. Of course, many of the other products are often used in a more convenient but insecure fashion as well.

**Specific to the APP, the one issue I found was:**

[Zoom iOS App sends data to Facebook](https://www.vice.com/en/article/k7e599/zoom-ios-app-sends-data-to-facebook-even-if-you-dont-have-a-facebook-account)

> As people work and socialize from home, video conferencing software
> Zoom has exploded in popularity. What the company and its privacy
> policy don't make clear is that the iOS version of the Zoom app is
> sending some analytics data to Facebook, **even if Zoom users don't have
> a Facebook account**, according to a Motherboard analysis of the app.

Comment: The problem that the company cited is with the app, not the service. The company allows the Zoom web client. All your points are about the service, not the app. So, you have not answered the question.

Comment: @user215422 - I updated and corrected my answer. Zoom still relays through a server but apparently they now support multiuser E2E. I have not yet tried it.

Comment: 1. Zoom bombing is still a threat 2. Why are you talking about a completely separate product? How is that relevant? 3. Zoom acquired Keybase in May 2020 to improve their E2E The improved version came out 6 months ago. 4. Commercial customers can specify where data is processed (US customers can keep all traffic and info in the US) FEDRAMP customers have even more control. So your point is only situationally relevant 5. **None of this answer addresses the app which is the question at hand**

Comment: That Facebook issue was reported 12 months ago and fixed.

Comment: Let me make this easier for you: sites have been keeping tabs on the apps and the service since March last year and everyone started using it. Here is the leading one (the one I told the OP to look at): https://www.tomsguide.com/uk/news/zoom-security-privacy-woes